# How to display the full text on hover over cell in UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, popup, hover

In a UITableView, I am having a set of values, some of which have a value longer than the width specified/drawn. I want a way to show the full value on hover over that cell, like we have on web pages.

Please advise a way to achieve this.

Comment: If you would like a code example I can provide that too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you really can't hover on a touch phone, I would use a **UILongPressGestureRecognizer** and have the action display a smaller subset view on the screen over the table view with the cells details.